# Android Nexus 7 Emulator sdcard subfolders not visible

Tags: android

I have created a Nexus 7 emulator under AVD Manager and it runs ok.

However, when I launch the Android Device Monitor and go to File Explorer, while I can see the mnt/sdcard folder, I cannot see any subfolders.

I can add a subfolder but it isn't visible, and if I try to add it again I get a 'folder exists' error.

I cannot remove folder, even if I have added it as above.

The image shows what I mean

[image]

I have the default emulator which I use also, and it works fine - all subfolders showing & allowing me to transfer files in & out.

How can I get the Nexus 7 emulator to show sdcard subfolders and allow me to transfer files?

Comment: If you run **`adb shell /mnt/sdcard`**, does it show the missing directories?

Comment: [mitch@Macintosh-3 platform-tools]$ ./adb shell /mnt/sdcard
/system/bin/sh: /mnt/sdcard: can't execute: Is a directory

Comment: Sorry, missed a bit: **`adb shell ls /mnt/sdcard`**.

Comment: [mitch@Macintosh-3 platform-tools]$ ./adb shell ls /mnt/sdcard
/mnt/sdcard - sorry comments dont show newlines - it returns /mnt/sdcard only

Comment: You might try creating a fresh emulator image from scratch. I cannot quite explain why neither Monitor nor **`adb`** can see what's in there. Make sure you set up "SD card" storage in the emulator image -- while I would expect a different message, what you're seeing would otherwise fit an emulator without any external storage.

Comment: Recreated emulator (checked in settings that it has hw.sdcard = yes). No change. However, if I ./adb shell, and once in the # prompt I can cd to the mnt/sdcard folder and ls and it shows a bunch of standard folders (Music, Pictures etc) along with my sixty5 folder, and I can cd into that. But none visible in ADM

Comment: Well, if you can see them via **`adb`**, it must be a bug somewhere in the Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

First, thanks to CommonsWare for setting me off on this tack :-)

The file permissions on the mnt/sdcard show an 'l' for a symlinked folder, pointing to storage/sdcard (you can actually see it on the above image but I didnt realise the significance)

Browsing to storage/sdcard in Android Device Monitor (instead of mnt/sdcard as with previous emulators) does then show all the folders and allows file transfer as normal.

This might be a feature of Android 5 (which I set up on the Nexus 7 emulator) vs Android 4.x which I have on the default emulator